# Pandas: replace column based on index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have the following problem: I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns with the same name.
I want to replace one of these particular column with new data (from another dataframe).
Note that I cannot use the syntax:

```
df['var_name'] = replacing_var_vals
```

Equivalent solution to my problem would be renaming a column based on index.

I've searched for hours but didn't find a solution to this easy task. 
Could you help?

Comment: What's wrong with renaming columns?

Comment: I didn't find a way to rename a particular column based on index, if, as it is the case, the database has columns with same names

Comment: You could use a work around by generating a new list of column names and  applying this list to the dataframe using `df.columns = list_with_names`

Comment: If you ok with renaming all columns you could do something like that: `df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(col, i) for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)]` ?

Comment: Use [iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) if you want to access it by position. For example, you can access the third column by `df.iloc[:, 2]`

Comment: I think you either have to rename your columns (like Anton and albert said) so you have unique names or access your duplicated columns per index (see ayhan's comment)

Comment: ayhan's solution was ok for my purpose, thanks! I tried to do the same but with the .ix method, didn't know about .iloc

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify the columns by its position, e.g., column j, then you can use `df.iloc[:, j] = values` to update values.

You can also access and update column labels using df.columns, e.g., `df.columns[5:7] = ['New label', 'New label 2']`